# Google Cloud Document AI processing response impossible to get Form Fields in PHP

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-platform, google-api-php-client, cloud-document-ai, google-cloud-php-client

I cannot get form fields values from processing a response in PHP when using a Google Cloud Document AI with a custom processor where the form fields are defined. `google-cloud` only has documentation for Java, C#, Pyton... How can I get my data? When I tested it in `googe-cloud` then everything worked...

[image: fields]

[image: code]

I try to looping over pages en so trying to get formFields but nothing works.

Comment: Do not post code as images, copy-paste code as text so others can help. Also add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you please provide more details. what you want to achieve? 
P.S - it seems like you operating with wrong Google resource.

Based on the code of SDK, i would assume that you need to use this method instead -- getEntities()

Answer (score 0):

Custom Document Extractor returns the extracted data in the `entities` field, not `formFields`.

The [Form Parser Processor](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_form-parser) is currently the only processor that populates the `formFields` field.

---

You can use this example to follow the logic for how to handle the response for Entity Extraction processors.

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#entities_nested_entities_and_normalized_values